# Is there a way to sync music between a PowerPC Mac and an iOS 7 device?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, leopard, powerpc

My friend has a G5 running 10.5 Leopard (the last supported version of OS X on PowerPC). However, after updating to iOS 7, syncing is no longer supported, as iOS 7 requires iTunes 11, which in turn requires 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Is there any way to get music sync functionality back on a PowerPC Mac without reverting to iOS 6, whether through some version of iTunes, or a 3rd-party tool, and without jailbreaking?

Comment: There is no way to downgrade a device to iOS 6.x once it has been upgraded to iOS 7.x unless you have saved the `SHSH` blobs and someone works out a way to downgrade the device. You won't be able to downgrade your iOS version once you have installed it to the latest, and you won't be able to install iTunes 11 on your PowerPC. They stopped support for iTunes on PowerPC from iTunes 10.7 onwards. ----------
**Edit:** I was looking for a link before. I couldn't find it. Found it again. Refer to [Just A Penguin](http://www.icj.me/ios/all), they have the complete list of iOS Firmware's currently wor

Comment: Let's leave this thread for non-reverting to iOS 6 answers since that's what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are many apps that can move data on and off an iDevice, albeit not in the same "sync" model that iTunes uses. Try the [trial of iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), for example.

Comment: iExplorer 3 requires 10.6. I'll give iExplorer 2 a try, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - multiple third party products allow Mac to write directly to iOS devices including PhoneView.

Their [requirements page lists 10.5 Mac and iOS 7 support](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/) for version 2.9.4 of the product.